# Django modelForm changes aspect when is submitted

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a web using django where a form is prompted to the user, that can fill some values of it and submit them. Then, the python program will fill the rest and show the form filled by the user, with also the fields filled by the server. I am using modelForms, as I want a complete matching between my model and my form.

For several reasons I have come to do it using the following code, but I don't know why after submitting the form, the fields don't appear as CharFields anymore, but as something similar to 'html labels', and are not editable anymore.

The code is a very simplified version of mine, where there is only one field, filled by the user.

views.py:

```
def manage_printers(request):
    p = PrinterForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if p.is_valid():
            f = p.save(commit=False)
            f.name = request.POST.get('name')
            f.save()
            return render_to_response('web.html', {'printer': f}) 
        else:
            return HttpResponse("form not valid")
    return render_to_response('web.html', {'printer': p}, )
```

models.py:

```
class Printer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=' ')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class PrinterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Printer
```

web.html:

```
<form action="/useriface/" method="post"> 
    <p>Name: {{ printer.name }}</p>
</form>
```

Comment: The code is doing exactly what you ask it to. You save the form, creating a `Printer` instance which you have called `f`. You pass that to the template, and display it.

Comment: What I want the code to do is show me the same form when is empty and when is filled. But when it is filled, it doesn't look like a form anymore, but like plain text. I wonder why if printer.name is defined as a CharField, it is not shown as that. I have also tried `<p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ printer.name }}"></p>`, but now from the beginning my printer.name charField is filled with the text `<input id=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained in the comment, when you save a form, you get a model instance. A model instance is not a form. It doesn't have form fields. When you pass the saved instance into the template in place of a form, you won't display form fields, you'll display the values of the saved instance's fields. If you want to redisplay the form, you should pass that into the template, not the saved instance.

Comment: Ok, now I get it thanks a lot. My code is more complicated than that, and what I want to do is to have, for example, an other field called "initials" (initially empty), that when a name is introduced, it returns in the corresponding textfield the first letter of the submitted name. If I work with the model instance that the save method returns, it is not displayed as a form anymore. So how can I modify the fields of a modelform, in order to pass it to the template? doing: 
`p = PrinterForm(request.POST or None)
p.initials = function_that_returns_first_letter(p.name)` doesn't work

Comment: Why can't you just pass the form, if you want to display the form?

Comment: Because I want to place a "submit" button between the "input" fields and the "output" fields. That's why I pass them to the template field by field. I tried to pass the form and it worked, but that's not what I want to do

Comment: But that has nothing to do with it! That's simply how you write the template, which doesn't change. One last time: when you save `p` to get `f`, **`f` is a model instance**. If you want to redisplay the form, `p`, then **pass `p` into the template, not `f`**.

Comment: I understand what you say, sorry but I think I didn't explain myself well. I want to work with the form, so that is what I am going to pass to the template. But what I don't know how to do is to use the same form to receive data from the user in some fields, and to output data from the server in other fields. For the first part I have no problem, but I don't know how can I edit some fields from the form. I try  `p = PrinterForm(request.POST or None) p.initials = "blah"`, but after rendering this p into the template, I still see the field "initials" empty. thanks a lot